# ServiceStack Redis Client GetValues when value is not present and is a value type

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

Running `ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClient.GetValues<int?>`, when any key is missing, I cannot map the values returned to keys. For example:

I ask for keys ("a1", "a2", "a3"). If there is no value associated with key "a2",
it simply returns (1, 3).

But I need to map each of this value to its corresponding key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetValuesMap` to return a dictionary of keys with their associated values, e.g:

```
var map = redis.GetValuesMap(new[] { "a1", "a2", "a3" }.ToList());
```

Keys without values will have a corresponding `null` Dictionary value.

Comment: The interface I was using did not have a 1:1 mapping to ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClient